# how to copy data from csv to a specific place in txt

Tags: python-2.7, csv

I get a csv file with a couple of columns, but I'm only interested in column nr 2 and 3.
The csv file looks like this:

```
ID,summary
15675,some summary
15678,some other summary

and so on
```

I need to copy those columns into an already existing txt file in a specific place:

```
Some text before

this_text_is_supposed_to_be_replaced_with_csv_data

some text after
```

The output I expect is the txt file which looks as follows:

```
   some text before
   15675,some summary
   15678,some other summary
   some text after
```

I figured it can be done with re.findall but I have no idea how to store data extracted from csv in a variable and replace the placeholder in the txt file with it.
I've come up with a piece of code that extracts the columns I'm interested in to a new txt file, but I have no idea how to copy them into the one I aleady have:

```
import csv
csv_file= "C:\\some\\url\\Desktop\\test.csv"
txt_file="C:\\some\\url\\Desktop\\test.txt"
text_list = []

with open(csv_file, "r") as my_input_file:
    my_input_file.__next__()
    for line in my_input_file:

        line = line.split(",", 2)
        text_list.append(" ".join(line[1:]))


with open(txt_file, "a") as my_output_file:
    for line in text_list:
        my_output_file.write(line)
```

Another thing I'd like to achieve is to create directories for every ID I get from column 2 in my csv file with a prefix 1_133345, 2_234355 and so on. Is there a way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A file cannot be changed in place - except if you're substituting exactly the same amount of data which is normally not the case. For this reason, you need to read the output file, change it, and then overwrite it. There are many ways of doing it, here's one of them

```
import csv

# Files
csv_file= "test.csv"
txt_file="test.txt"

# Lines to match
before = "Some text before\n"
after = "some text after\n"

# Read the input file
whole_text = []
text_list = []
numbers = []
with open(csv_file, "r") as my_input_file:
    next(my_input_file)
    for line in my_input_file:
        whole_text.append(line)
        line = line.split(",", 2)
        numbers.append(line[:1])
        text_list.append(" ".join(line[1:]))

# Read the output file 
with open(txt_file, "r") as my_output_file:
    lines = my_output_file.readlines()

# Write the changed output file  
bf = lines.index(before)
af = lines.index(after)
with open("test.txt", "w") as my_output_file:
    my_output_file.write("".join(lines[:bf+1]))
    my_output_file.write("".join(whole_text))
    my_output_file.write("".join(lines[af:]))
```

This program is based on several assumptions:

- Like in the post, you recognize the spot where you want to change the content based on two specific known lines.
- You don't need to do anything else with the columns hence you don't need to do any newline removal and can just pass the whole lines as read.
- The desired output has the numbers in them, while the `text_list` list was created for some other purpose.

With this, the program reads the input file and splits it into three lists - one with the entire content, second with just the numbers (for directory naming in the later part of the question) and third with text only. It the reads the whole output file all at once. It finds the indices of bordering lines you want to keep, `bf` and `af`. It opens the output file again and writes the content up until `bf` inclusive. It then writes the new content and finally the old content, starting from `af`. Note that `next()` actually worked for me while your version did not - I am using Python 2.7.